# How Quit Sed When Matched

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a text file like 
 
    `aaaa
    aaaa
    aaaa
    aaaa
    ....`

I use the **sed** to replace the string of "aaaa" with "bbbb", the command is

`sed -i "/aaaa/c\bbbb"  mytextfile`

but I want the sed to stop processing when it finds first match.The output will be like this
 
    `bbbb
    aaaa
    aaaa
    aaaa
    ....`

 Anybody tells how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sed '0,/aaaa/{s/aaaa/bbbb/}' mytextfile
```